# Django - querying by a for loop

Tags: python, django

I have to fetch the total wrote posts number by each user

```
@staff_member_required
def counter(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().count()
    users = User.objects.all()
    for user in users.iterator():
        written_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user).count()

    context = {'users': users, 'written_posts': written_posts, 'posts': posts, 'num': num}
    return render(request, 'account/counter.html', context)
```

But it returns me for all users the same user's number of posts. Anyone can give a piece of advice?

Answer (score 4):

You're returning within the loop, so it only "finds" the first user.

Anyway, instead of manually looping, use the [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/) function:

```
from django.db.models import Count

@staff_member_required
def counter(request):
    users = User.objects.all().annotate(post_count=Count('post_set'))
    context = {'users': users}
    return render(request, 'account/counter.html', context)
```

Now you can do

```
{% for user in users %}
{{ user }} has {{ user.post_count }} posts
{% endfor %}
```

in the template.

Comment: The "within loop stuff " was just a mess trying, but it's not working else out the loop. Anyway in your "users" where are you calling Post model? Sorry but i don't know annotate

Comment: It works, thank you. Have any documentation about annotate? Cause i've not understood it

Comment: Yes, I linked the documentation - click the `annotate` keyword in my answer.